# Inserting a structure to the vector

Tags: c++, vector, structure

i am writing a program (address book) and i have a small problem with one of the functions. I am sending to it my string e.g. 1|John|Smith|333 222 111|john@smith.pl|Happy Street 3a; 33-300 Krakow| and I want to divide it when the compiler find the "|",and then I want to insert each of this elements into a structure. I am givig my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct Addressee
{
int id = 0;
string name = "", surname = "", telephone_number = "", email = "", address = "";
};

int main()
{
vector <Addressee> someone;
Addressee inserted;
string informationaAboutAddressee [6];
cout << "Insert data about Your friend: ";
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    getline(cin,informationaAboutAddressee[i], '|');
    }
    inserted.id = atoi(informationaAboutAddressee[0].c_str());
    inserted.name = informationaAboutAddressee[1];
    inserted.surname = informationaAboutAddressee[2];
    inserted.telephone_number = informationaAboutAddressee[3];
    inserted.email = informationaAboutAddressee[4];
    inserted.address = informationaAboutAddressee[5];
    someone.push_back(inserted);
}

for(int i = 0; i < someone.size(); i++)
{
     cout << "Addressee number " << i << ": ";
     cout << someone[i].id << " ";
     cout << someone[i].name << " ";
     cout << someone[i].surname << " ";
     cout << someone[i].telephone_number << " ";
     cout << someone[i].email << " ";
     cout << someone[i].address << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Should i change something or this will actually work? when i am compiling it - it wroks just fine, bt when i am applying it to my "master" program and I want to show all the addressee vector is empty :/ there is only one difference - here i am always writig a new string, but when it is working as a function i am sending here a string inserted ealier and downloaded from a file.

I'm a still a newbie so please, be gentle ;)

I will give to You two functions that should cooperate:

```
Addressee downloadAddresseeInfo(string addresseeInfo)
{
Adresat inserted;
int id = 0;
string name, surname, telephone_number, email, address;
string buffer [6] = informationaAboutAddressee;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    getline(cin,informationaAboutAddressee[i], '|');
    }
    inserted.id = atoi(informationaAboutAddressee[0].c_str());
    inserted.name = informationaAboutAddressee[1];
    inserted.surname = informationaAboutAddressee[2];
    inserted.telephone_number = informationaAboutAddressee[3];
    inserted.email = informationaAboutAddressee[4];
    inserted.address = informationaAboutAddressee[5];

return inserted;
}

void downloadFromFile(vector<Addressee> &someone)
{
Addressee oneAddressee;
string addresseeInfo = "";

fstream textFile;
textFile.open("KsiazkaAdresowa.txt", ios::in);

if (textFile.good() == true)
{
    while (getline(textFile, addresseeInfo))
    {
        oneAddressee = downloadAddresseeInfo(addresseeInfo);

        someone.push_back(oneAddressee);
    }
    textFile.close();
}
}
```

Comment: "bt when i am applying it to my "master" program and I want to show all the addressee vector is empty" .. please provide a [mcve] for the not working code. The code you posted here seems to be fine, or isnt it?

Comment: OT: in your struct `string name = "", surname = "", telephone_number = "", email = "", address = "";` you don't need to do this. The default constructor will be enough.

Comment: So there is a difference between the code here, and your "master" program. You'll need to explore the differences until you find the one causing the problem. Since we cannot see them, we cannot help.

Comment: Rewrite your code as a function `std::vector<Addressee> parseInputData(std::istream& input);`, prepare testing data (in a file or whatever), then test it, and finally if it doesn't work, debug it step by step. If it still doesn't work, post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Undoubtedly the problem is in your master program, so that is the program you should show us, not the program that is working. Newbie or not, it seems obvious really.

Comment: Not quite: you shouldn't show your master program; producing an abstracted example was the right thing to do. But it does have to actually demonstrate the problem, otherwise it's obviously worthless.

Comment: @Biedrzyk - _I want to divide it when the compiler find the "|"…_ - The one who executes your program is not the compiler.

Comment: my bad - it was late, and i Was exhausted after a long day ;) i have edited my post and added the two functions that should cooperate.

Comment: Prefer to use [`operator>>` and `operator<<`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41954d47a71d6003)